# Display data as group using datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I have a datatable which looks like this..

```
s.no product categoryno 

1.   product1    1
2.   product2    1
3.   product3    1
4.   Product4    2
5.   Product5    2
6.   product6    2
```

Now I want to bind this datatable to a datalist as

```
some tittle:

 product1
 product2
 product3

some tittle:

 product4
 product5
 product6
```

I need to separate the data according to a column(like category in above example) and display it using datalist.Any sugessions will be appreciated..

**NOTE**: Product denotes image of the product whose path is in database..

Comment: I think, it would be easy if you could do a select query to your database to `get the data as expected to your DataTable` and then bind to a single DataList.

Comment: @Kaf i already have data separately for categories.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two `DataTables` (as per comments), you could add a relationship between two tables using `categoryno` and then bind it to the `Datalist` as below.

```
//Assuming your datatables are in ds (DataSet)

ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Cats";
ds.Tables[1].TableName = "Products";
ds.Relations.Add("children", ds.Tables["Cats"].Columns["categoryno"],
                             ds.Tables["Products"].Columns["categoryno"]);
YourDataList.DataSource = ds;
YourDataList.DataBind();
```

**UPDATE:** as per recent comments I think you just need to add the rows from one to the other.

```
foreach(DataRow dr2 in Table2.Rows)
{
   DataRow dr1 = Table1.NewRow(); 
   dr1[0] = dr2[0];
   dr1[1] = dr2[1];
   dr1[2] = dr2[2];
   //... if you have many columns 
   Table1.Rows.Add(dr1);
}
//Bind Table1 here
```

Comment: If you use `DataTables` you could easlily use a `DataSet` to build a relationship. This should be working. `categoryno` should be available in both tables and if not, should be replaced with appropriate (related) column names.

Comment: It gives an error like this **these columns don't currently have unique values**

Comment: I think you need to make sure `Categories are a distinct list`.

Comment: can't get you man..I have two datatables one with categoryno 1 and other with categoryno 2.

Comment: Well, you said **"i already have data separately for categories"** in the comments right? so I understood it as you have two tables one with categories and other with products. Sounds like you have two datatables with same data and you need to join them. I will update.

Comment: sorry man i told wrongly.As i said in the above comment **i have 2 datables one with products of category 1 and other with products of category 2**.Also i don not want to join datas.I need to display it separately in same datalist.

Comment: Well, use a new DataTable and add the rows as shown above. I think the method is clear now.

Comment: hey i dont want combine both datatables.I want to bind both datatables separately in same datalist.

Comment: As I said before, if you don't want to add them to a existing table, **use a new DataTable and add the rows as shown above**

Answer (score 0):

```
    ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Cats";
    ds.Tables[1].TableName = "Products";
    ds.Relations.Add("children",       ds.Tables["Cats"].Columns["categoryno"],ds.Tables["Products"].Columns["categoryno"]);
    YourDataList.DataSource = ds;
    YourDataList.DataBind();
```